# Underfull \hbox when putting two tabulars side by side

Tags: tables

I want to make the right tabular positioning from 50% of the textwidth, so I put 2 slightly smaller tabulars side by side and fill with a `hskip` and a `hfill` to avoid overfulling.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\section{Tables}

    \begin{tabular*}{.49\textwidth}{ll}
        a & b \\ [.375em]
        c & d
    \end{tabular*} \hskip .01\textwidth
    \begin{tabular*}{.49\textwidth}{ll}
        e & f \\ [.375em]
        g & h
    \end{tabular*} \hfill

\end{document}
```

However, this ends up with underfulling (under xelatex).

```
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in alignment at lines 9--12
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in alignment at lines 13--16
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 9--17
```

How to put these two tabulars side by side without a warning?

Comment: Welcome! It probably doesn't like the lack of stuff *in* the tabulars. Two characters for almost half the page width isn't much. You've not given a proper example, but unless you have a very small text width, that's going to look awful. Why not use a regular `tabular` and just use `\centering` or `\hfill`s or whatever?

Comment: @cfr I edited my question and added a MWE.

Comment: Simply leave out the `hfill` at the end? (I'd leave out also the `\hskip` in the middle or substitute it with an `\hfill`).

Comment: Off-topic: you don't need to load `tabularx` to use `tabular*`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, having `\section` makes you disregard the indent.

If you want the left table to start at the left margin and the right table at mid line, you can use two appropriately sized boxes.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\makebox[.5\textwidth][l]{%
  \begin{tabular}{@{}ll@{}}
  a & b \\ [.375em]
  c & d
  \end{tabular}% <--- don't forget %
}% <--- don't forget %
\makebox[.5\textwidth][l]{%
  \begin{tabular}{@{}ll@{}}
  e & f \\ [.375em]
  g & h
  \end{tabular}% <--- don't forget %
}

% this is to show the center of the text width
\noindent
\rule{.5\textwidth}{0.4pt}%
\makebox[0pt]{\rule{0.4pt}{.5cm}}%
\rule{.5\textwidth}{0.4pt}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The `Underfull \hbox` messages were mainly due to `tabular*` not being given flexible intercolumn glue.

The `\hfill` at the end is removed, because it is followed by `\par`, so it is irrelevant. Hence the line ends up consisting of

1. a tabular 0.49 of the text width;
2. a standard interword space (the space between `\end{tabular*}` and `\hskip`;
3. glue for 0.01 of the text width;
4. a tabular 0.49 of the text width;
5. a standard interword space (the space between `\end{tabular*}` and `\hfill`).

Beware of unwanted spaces.

The line is actually overfull, so the *second line* of the paragraph turns out to be underfull, because it has nothing in it. You probaby didn't notice

```
Overfull \hbox (13.77411pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 9--17
```

Comment: I am curious about why the original code doesn't end up with overfull rather than underfull? Does that means those interword spaces is shorter than 0.01 of the text width?

Comment: @KevinDong You got an overfull and an underfull box.

Comment: There are exactly three underfull warnings when compiling with the latest XeTeX. Thanks for you detailed answer.

Comment: I don't get an overfull box warning with pdfLaTeX with the OP's MWE. Maybe the MWE changed and you were working with an earlier version? @KevinDong Did you originally post an example without the section preceding the first tabular?

Comment: @KevinDong I see that you did. Even though egreg answered after you'd edited the code in the question again, I'm assuming that the answer is based on the earlier MWE you posted, which didn't have a section heading. Without the section heading, you get the additional warning mentioned. With the section heading, you don't, because then there's no indentation here.

Comment: @cfr I did post a MWE without section at first, since I did not know that it would change the behaviour of indention. Thanks for telling me that without `%` it will add an extra space and make it overfill, since I thought latex syntax is whitespace-insensitive. Actually, I would like to make the right tabular without column separation only, but I did not add this into the question to make it edited too many times. The final code is also posted below for anyone who needs it.

Comment: @KevinDong That explains the difference in warnings, I think. If you remove the section, you'll see the overfull one, too.

Answer (score 0):

This issue can be solved by using two minipages.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\section{Tables}

    \begin{tabularx}{.5\textwidth}{ll@{\extracolsep{\fill}}l} % normal
        a & b \\ [.375em]
        c & d
    \end{tabularx}% <-- this is important to avoid overfull
    \begin{tabularx}{.5\textwidth}{@{}ll@{\extracolsep{\fill}}l} % no column separation
        e & f \\ [.375em]
        g & h
    \end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

Comment: this still has parindent to the left of the first minipage and a word space before the hskip so the second minipage does not start at .5\textwidth from the left.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Doesn't LaTeX by default not indent the first paragraph following a section heading?

Comment: @cfr well yes, I hadn't spotted the section had been added to the answer (and it's not mentioned in the text of the answer but is possibly the main part of the solution as it accounts for ~15pt difference in the line, so I'll leave my comment even if not completely accurate)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle It isn't added in the answer. It is copied from the question.

Comment: @cfr check the question edit history:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I already did: see my comments on egreg's answer. But the question was edited before any of the answers were posted, I think. egreg seems to have been looking at an outdated version of the question. (But I don't know how accurate the time stamps produced by the site are, so maybe these are misleading.)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle But it means there is no reason for these answers to mention adding the `\section` as part of the solution, doesn't it?

Comment: @cfr well it would be a good idea as typically you can not assume just because there is no intervening text in an mwe that there is none in the real document. There is no need for guesses like .49\textwidth, two boxes of width .5\textwidth will fit, but it would be helpful to say why they fit in this case.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle OK. I agree it would be a good idea but it is still not part of the solution as such, because it is already in the code in the question. It would probably be a good idea to add `\noindent` in any case, in case something is later added or the tables are moved. But it is because the section is in the question that the OP gets only 3 warning lines and not the overfull one egreg mentions, which is the source of some muddling in the discussion. So what is and isn't being changed in the solutions matters in terms of explaining why just those 3 lines are produced in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of other better options to avoid such warnings like `tabularx` or using normal `tabular`s inside `minipage`s as you did, etc. But, to know the source of these `Underfull` warnings you need to look more carefully at your code.

For the last `Underfull` warning, remove that final `\hfill`, `\hfill` should be used between text and not at the end. For the other two warnings, you have too short text in the tables, shorter than `.49\textwidth`. To avoid this, add `@{\extracolsep{\fill}}` to tabular headers. Finally, instead of `\hskip .01\textwidth` between the two tabulars, use `\hfill`, it will ensure filling up the whole line width automatically.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\begin{document}

\section{Tables}

    \begin{tabular*}{.49\textwidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}l}
        a & b \\ [.375em]
        c & d 
    \end{tabular*} \hfill %\hskip .01\textwidth    
    \begin{tabular*}{.49\textwidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}l}
        e & f \\ [.375em]
        g & h
    \end{tabular*} 

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: This does not meet the requirement that the second tabular should start from 50% of the textwidth.